# Lower bound on $\sum_{i=1}^N i^k$ for $k>0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I want to find a  lower bound on the following sum
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N i^k
\end{align}
where $k>0$.

Clearly, we have that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N i^k \le  N^{k+1}
\end{align}

**Now, I after a firm lower bound**

It is easy to see that because of the polynomial structure 
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N i^k \ge c N^{k+1}
\end{align}
where $c$ is some positive constant.

However, this is not a firm bound.  What would be method to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}i^k=\int_{1}^{N+1}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor ^k\,dx \leq \int_{1}^{N+1}x^k\,dx \leq \frac{(N+1)^{k+1}}{\color{blue}{k+1}}$$
and in a similar fashion
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}i^k=\int_{0}^{N}\left\lceil x \right\rceil^k\,dx \geq \int_{0}^{N}x^k\,dx = \frac{N^{k+1}}{\color{blue}{k+1}}.$$
Sharper bounds can be derived from the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality), for instance.

Comment: The Hermite-Hadamard inequality would only work if $k\ge 1$, right? Since it requires convexity?

Comment: @Lisa: of course, but if we are dealing with a concave function the reverse HHI inequality holds.